# SKobbler location accuracy in android

Tags: android, skmaps

I am implementing custom turn-by-turn navigation using SKMaps. I am getting gps location using gpsProvider(SKCurrentPositionProvider --> gpsProvider enabled).

The location provider gives accurate location when my device is connected in wifi. If I switch the network to 3G (turn off wifi), the location provider produces wrong location results.

How to overcome this issue? Please provide some suggestions to overcome this issue.

```
private void setGpsProviders() {
    currentPositionProvider = new SKCurrentPositionProvider(activity);
    currentPositionProvider.setCurrentPositionListener(activity);

    if (SKNavigationUtils.hasGpsModule(activity)) {
        currentPositionProvider.requestLocationUpdates(true, false, true); //useGpsProvider, useNetworkProvider, usePassiveProvider
    } else if (SKNavigationUtils.hasNetworkModule(activity)) {
        currentPositionProvider.requestLocationUpdates(false, true, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code snippet that you are using

Answer (score 0):

All right, the mobile network gives very low accuracy of coordinates (from a few hundred meters to several kilometers), while the accuracy WiFi has several tens of meters.
Make sure that you have turned on GPS in your phone. This can be done in the code:

```
//import android.location.LocationManager;    
public static boolean isGPSEnabled (Context context) {
             LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
             return manager.isProviderEnabled (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

         }
```